# Extracting Outh2 credentials in App Engine set by Python decorator

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0

I'm writing an app where I used [the Python decorators](http://google-api-python-client.googlecode.com/hg/docs/epy/oauth2client.appengine.OAuth2Decorator-class.html) from [Google's Client Library for for Python](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth) to streamline the flow to have my app access Google APIs. However, I've hit a point where I need to extract the actual credential and authorize manually for a helper method. In my App Engine Datastore Viewer in the dashboard, I have a CredentialsModel object with entities, but I can't access them programmatically with this code:

```
creds = StorageByKeyName(CredentialsModel, 'username', 'credentials').get()
```

It always generates "NameError: global name 'CredentialsModel' is not defined". How can I pull the credential value out of the storage that the decorators use with the right model name? Thanks for the help!

Comment: did you import the `CredentialsModel`? (i.e., `from models import CredentialsModel` or something like that)

Comment: Yep, sure did. It still won't take. I wonder if accessing the Storage object directly would be any better...

Comment: well the error you have is because `CredentialsModel` isn't in scope where you're calling this. Has nothing to do with GAE, totally Python-side.

Answer (score 0):

So I think I've figured it out....but I hope someone can prove me wrong. The helper method in which I'm trying to extract the OAuth 2.0 credential for is a webhook endpoint, which the Python decorators for the App Engine libs don't seem to play very well with. They're great for publicly-accessible URLs that can be browsed to by human users, but I can't seem to make it work when a remote API pings my designated URL using the decorator logic.

I'm going to rewrite the OAuth layer from scratch and do things manually. :)